# jQuery put autocomplete result in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `input` value that has the id `word` and a jQuery function like this:

```
$(function() {
var availableTags = ["register", "malloc", "device", "apre", "fallo"];
$("#word").autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
});
```

When I type the text in my input, the jQuery function is called, and it shows me the results. Here you can see an example:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cUu97f1.png]

I typed "al" and it shows all the words (in the array) containing these letters. It's fine here, but my problem is the following. I want the result to be displayed in the `textarea`, and not as a list.

It means that `malloc` and `fallo` must be inside the textarea.

Do you have any suggestion? You can find the fiddle with the full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TVq9g/3/).

Comment: Kind of like the autocomplete in Microsoft Excel -- As you type, the best matching result is shown in the text box, and as you continue typing, the best match changes?

Comment: Yes, you're right. But this is not the problem, I only want the text to be put inside the textarea. I don't want the list

Comment: Is this what you want?  If it is, tell me so I can put it in an answer: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/bcY56/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kPG4C/1/) is a fiddle that will hide the autocomplete menu items and update the textarea with the returned items.  Notice that the menu is still there, just hidden, so as not to break the autocomplete widget. The idea is to use the response method of the widget to load the textarea with the appropriate values.  Note that this will hide all autocomplete menus on the page and will not clear out the textbox when the user clears out all of the tet in the input, but it should give you a start.

CSS to hide the autocomplete menu items:

```
.ui-autocomplete li { display: none; }
```

Additional code to grab the responses for the textarea:

```
$( "#word" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            response: function( event, ui ) {
                $("#testo").val(ui.content.map(function(d) { 
                    return d.label; 
                }).join("\n"));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to override the plugin's [`_renderMenu`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderMenu) function.

Here's a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TVq9g/4/

Comment: I had tried this too, but the problem is that you lose the up/down functionality because the <ul> element is no longer there.  Considering the text above the input box I'm assuming the OP wants to keep this ability.  Overall though, I do think overriding _renderMenu would be a better option than my solution as long as it doesn't break the widget in any way.